# how do i get the correct id with the query results

Tags: mysql, sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I want to create a stored procedure in MySQL, but first, I want to get the query right. However, I keep getting the problem that I can't seem to get the correct id back from my query that correspond with the DateTime stamps that I get back.

this is the table I am trying to get the result from:

```
id  EventId   start                 end
1   1         2019-04-05 00:00:00   2019-04-07 00:00:00
2   2         2020-04-03 00:00:00   2020-04-03 00:00:00
3   3         2020-04-02 00:00:00   2020-04-02 00:00:00
7   1         2020-06-11 00:00:00   2020-06-11 00:00:00
9   2         2020-06-18 00:00:00   2020-06-18 00:00:00
10  3         2020-06-11 00:00:00   2020-06-11 00:00:00
11  3         2020-06-07 00:00:00   2020-06-07 00:00:00
```

query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Eventid, MIN(start), id
from date_planning
WHERE `start` >= NOW()
GROUP BY Eventid
```

this gives me the following result

```
EventId   Min(start)            id
1         2020-06-11 00:00:00   3
2         2020-06-18 00:00:00   9
3         2020-06-07 00:00:00   10
```

but these are the correct ids that belong to those DateTimes:

```
EventId   Min(start)            id
1         2020-06-11 00:00:00   7
2         2020-06-18 00:00:00   9
3         2020-06-07 00:00:00   11
```

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. Your query will raise an exception in newer MySQL versions, unless in compatibility mode.

Comment: However, current MySQL has window functions. Check them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the row with the minimum "future" date for each `eventId`. To solve this greatest-n-per-group problem, you need to filter rather than aggregate. Here is one option using a correlated subquery:

```
select dt.*
from date_planning dt
where dt.start = (
    select min(dt1.start)
    from date_planning dt1
    where dt1.eventId = dt.eventId and dt1.start >= now()
)
```

For performance, you need an index on `(eventId, start)`.